# How to know if all applications corresponding to a Windows Service are closed?

Tags: batch-file, windows-services

I am using Quartz.NET server (a windows service) for scheduling some jobs. These jobs are mostly batch files. They open a console (when used without the service), do some database work and display some messages to the user and then they are automatically closed. However, there still exists a thin chance I have considered that the console windows stay open. If they are run under the service, I am not able to see what processes are running. So I am putting flags on my programs so that each run will indicate if a job has started, is in progress or is finished. But how can one be sure if the program is completely shut down due to an unknown error?

Is there a way to see what programs the service has triggered so that we could close them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wmic process get processid, parentprocessid, name
```

or if you know the id

```
wmic process where (parentprocessid=312) get processid, parentprocessid, name
```

Comment: is there a way to see all the processes run via a specific service? The command you suggested outputs all the current processes.

Comment: Get the PID of the service and use second command. You can get it with tasklist. `tasklist /svc`. If your service is sharing a process (eg svchost.exe) with other services then you get all services in that process.